# Difference between forward/backward slicing and reaching definition - def/use - use/def chains

Tags: data-flow-analysis

I'm a little bit confused about the difference between forward/backward slicing and the use/def-def/use as part of the reaching definitions technique. Isn't the use-def chain supposed to be equivalent to the backward slicing?

Let's assume we have a line that uses some variables. Like: `x = y + z`.

If we try to find all the code locations that influenced the given code line (backward slicing), shouldn't it be the same as all the entries of the use-def chain of the variable `x`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing

Comment: (If you edit your question, e.g. to add your line of thought *why* both might (always?) be the same, please correct the typo in the title.)

Answer (score 1):

Backward slicing includes both data and control dependencies while ud-chains consider only data depedencies.